# Debugging onMouseOver and onMouseOut with javascript and less css

Tags: javascript, html, less

I have got some problems here finding my mistake. Debugging Console says:" Can't find variable: mouseover/mouseout." I don't know what she's trying to say to me. I want to fade a div with lessCss to 50% transparency with the onmouseover/onmouseout event.

```
<div id="right" class="" onMouseOver="javascript: mouseover(this);" onMouseOut="javascript: mouseout(this);"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function mouseover(this) {
    this.setAttribute("class", "mouseover");
  }

  function mouseout(this) {
    this.setAttribute("class", "");
  }
</script>
```

lessCss code:

```
#right {
  position:fixed;
  top:320px;
  right:0px;
  z-index:5;
  height:200px;
  width:30px;
  background-image: url(images/right);
  border-radius:5px;
  background-color:fade(darken(@bg-color, 50%),50%);
  cursor:pointer;
}
.mouseover {
  background-color:darken(@bg-color, 50%);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need a javascript function, use CSS selector "hover":

```
#right {
position:fixed;
top:320px;
right:0px;
z-index:5;
height:200px;
width:30px;
background-image: url(images/right);
border-radius:5px;
background-color:fade(darken(@bg-color, 50%),50%);
cursor:pointer;
}
#right:hover {
background-color:darken(@bg-color, 50%);
}
```

Your div will simply need to have "right" as id:

```
<div id="right"></div>
```